# How to move all data and metadata from Sandbox to Developer Edition?

Tags: sandbox, data, developer-edition

How to move all org data (Objects, records, Apex classes, VF pages, Triggers, Validation Rules) from Sandbox to Developer Edition?

Answer (score 1):

For all of that, except records (assuming this is your org's data), you can use the [Force.com Migration tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Migration_Tool) or the [Force.com IDE for Eclipse](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE).

To migrate your data you can use Data Loader.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a point and click way, you can use a change set to move everything but the data. More details can be found here http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dev_lifecycle/

As Frank mentioned you can use data loader to export from the sandbox and then into production.  I like using jitterbit's free tool. You cannot keep salesforce IDS between orgs,  so if you have any related data you will need to create an 18 character external ID on the parent then do upserts on the children records.

Answer (score 0):

Three ways:

1. Use mavensmate if you write apex with Sublime.
2. Use Salesforce Migration Tools(Ant).
3. Use Salesforce Eclipse plugin to deploy your resources to Developer Edition.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I tried the Mavensmate and Force.com IDE. I am facing one problem: there is one app package in Sandbox that cannot be deployed to Developer Edition. That app does effect on standard and custom objects and I can't deploy them. How to bypass that app when deploying?